# Training using LM algorithm in Neural Network Toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to use the Neural Toolbox in MATLAB to train a dataset using the LM algorithm. The network architecture I am using is feedforward with one hidden layer while the transfer functions I am using is the tansig for input-to-hidden layer and pureline for hidden-to-output layer. During training, the values of MSE with increasing number of epochs shows up on the screen till the performance goal is met, or the maximum no. of epochs is reached. However, what I am interested is in is to save the value of MSE at each epoch from the start till the end of training as a datafile (.txt or .dat) in my hard drive. I have browsed a lot but I could not find a way to do this. Can someone please help me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

If you create you code with network called net then you can get the information about MSE using the function [net tr ] = train(net,x,t).
For instance if we use simplefit_dataset simple data with a simple network the result is on tr.perf which shows that MSE for each epoch for the train data:

```
close all, clear all, clc, plt=0;
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = fitnet(10);
rng(0)
[net tr ] = train(net, x, t);
plt = plt+1, figure(plt), hold on;
plot(tr.perf,'b', 'LineWidth', 2)
```

For more information,please visit the following link:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57648-how-to-plot-mse-for-train-and-test

Comment: I have run the sample code you sent and it does plot the MSE with the number of iterations. However, when I try to save the "tr" file as a .dat file on my hard drive, I get the message: "Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file. ariable 'tr' not written to file". So my problem of saving the MSE at each epoch during training as a .dat or .txt file on my hard drive still remains unresolved. However, MATLAB does save this tr file as a file with a .mat extension with a 1x1 size and I still dont have an idea how to open this type of file in any application on my computer. I would

Answer (score 0):

To save the output results in a text file please use the following code:

```
fileID = fopen('Output.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%f\n',tr.perf);
fclose(fileID);
```

For more information about writing and reading data from/to the text in matlab refer to the below link:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html

Answer (score 0):

All results of mlp_ANN toolbax is in tr variable on workspace.you have not to do anything as writing code to get MSE for each epoch.All you need is that go into the tr variable on workspace after halting train and open the pref and copy it to notpad as .txt file.